# Working with JSON columns in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a project. At the moment, I am working with a CV (curriculum vitae) table. So, I was at the point that each CV can contain one or more Phone numbers and e-mails.

Because I already had around 7 tables associated with CV like skills, languages and so on, I decided to save emails and phones in the Сv
s columns, as JSON columns.

So, in my migration I put

```
$table->json('phone');
$table->json('email');
```

How could I manipulate this

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]"> 
 <input type="text" name="email[]">
```

for storing this data from Controller in DB, and how should I retrieve them in view?

Comment: from my understanding you are creating TWO json fields in the database and gain nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I want to store 1 or multiple phone numbers in one column as JSON, an then in view to retrive that json and output JSON objects with foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute casting. In this case, you'll not need to convert the data from array to JSON and back.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model

```
protected $casts = [
    'phone' => 'array',
    'email' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide some pseudo-code how it should look in Controller for saving, and outputing in Blade?
Thanks!

Comment: @priMo-ex3m just work with the array as usual `$model = new Model; $model->phone = $request->phone; $model->save();`

Comment: So, if from front-end to back-end came array like 
` $request->phone = [ 079111000, 069333555, 073666432 ] ; ` , `$model->phone` will save it automatically as `JSON column`, yep?

But, when retrieving this `$model->phone` in `Blade`, how should I iterate through `JSON` objects in that case?
Thanks.

Comment: @priMo-ex3m in the view you can iterate over the data as through an array.